# Django Foreign Key not matching

Tags: python, django-models

I have a model in Django called `NewsArticle` :

```
class NewsArticle(models.Model):
    """
    News articles from the NBA. News is generated even after the regular season
    """

    source = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    time_ago = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    content = models.TextField(default="Not Available")
    cat = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="N/A")
    
    # Foreign Keys
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    og_source = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    og_url = models.URLField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.title}"
```

which has a foreign key for another class called `Player`.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    """
    Player Info
    """
   
    # Primary Key
    playerid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, default="N/A")

    height = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    exp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    pos_cat = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    sec_pos = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True)
    headshot = models.URLField(null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}"
```

I wrote a function that pulls data from an API in JSON format and insert it into the models.

```
def init_player():
    """
    Initialize the Player model.
    """
    # GET Request to SportsData.io
    rq = requests.request("GET", f"https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/scores/json/Players?key={key}")
    rq = rq.json()

    # Create Player loop
    for p in rq:
        player = Player(playerid=p['PlayerID'],
                        last_name=p['LastName'],
                        first_name=p['FirstName'],
                        team=p['Team'],
                        height=p['Height'],
                        weight=p['Weight'],
                        exp=p['Experience'],
                        pos_cat=p['PositionCategory'],
                        sec_pos=p['DepthChartPosition'],
                        headshot=p['UsaTodayHeadshotNoBackgroundUrl'])

        player.save()


def init_news():
    """
    Initialize the News model.
    """
    # GET Request to SportsData.io
    rq = requests.request("GET", f"https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/scores/json/News?key={key}")
    rq = rq.json()

    # Create News loop
    for n in rq:
        news = NewsArticle(source=n['Source'],
                           url=n['Url'],
                           time_ago=n['TimeAgo'],
                           date=n['Updated'],
                           title=n['Title'],
                           content=n['Content'],
                           cat=n['Categories'],
                           player=n['PlayerID'],
                           team=n['Team'],
                           og_source=n['OriginalSource'],
                           og_url=n['OriginalSourceUrl'])

        news.save()
```

When I run the `init_news()` after I ran `init_player()` I get a `ValueError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mtthw\WebDevProjects\FantasyStock\fantasy_stock\nba\db_init.py", line 76, in <module>
    init_news()
  File "C:\Users\mtthw\WebDevProjects\FantasyStock\fantasy_stock\nba\db_init.py", line 60, in init_news
    news = NewsArticle(source=n['Source'],
  File "C:\Users\mtthw\WebDevProjects\FantasyStock\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 561, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\Users\mtthw\WebDevProjects\FantasyStock\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 235, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "20001447": "NewsArticle.player" must be a "Player" instance.
```

I was able to successfully run the `init_player()` function.

After investigating, it looks like the PlayerID from the function is being inserted as a string and trying to match the string PlayerID with the integer PlayerID, which is causing a `ValueError`.

Is there a way to convert `playerid` to an integer in the `init_news()` function?

Here is a sample of the JSON:

```
[{"NewsID":84827,"Source":"RotoBaller","Updated":"2022-09-14T00:47:31","TimeAgo":"23 hours ago","Title":"Montrezl Harrell Officially A Sixer","Content":"Free-agent forward\/center Montrezl Harrell is officially a Sixer, according to a press release from the team. The deal is worth over $5 million, and the second year of the contract is a player option. The 28-year-old has an impressive resume, posting career averages of 12.9 points and 5.3 rebounds while earning the Sixth Man of the Year award in 2020. With Harrell's legal issues behind him, he'll look for a fresh start in Philly and presumably support Joel Embiid from off the bench. He may even start here and there throughout the season. Either way, Harrell should see plenty of attention from deep league fantasy managers heading into the year.","Url":"https:\/\/www.rotoballer.com\/player-news\/montrezl-harrell-officially-a-sixer\/1066344","TermsOfUse":"RotoBaller Premium News feeds are provided for commercial use and in accordance to the terms set forth within your SportsDataIO's commercial agreement. Please contact sales@sportsdata.io with any questions.","Author":"Staff","Categories":"Lineup, Transactions","PlayerID":20001447,"TeamID":7,"Team":"PHI","PlayerID2":null,"TeamID2":null,"Team2":null,"OriginalSource":"NBA.com","OriginalSourceUrl":"https:\/\/www.nba.com\/stats\/transactions\/"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `player=n['PlayerID']` the method `create` is expecting player object, You can use `player_id` same for team, but you should ensure that there is a player and a team with those IDs in your DB

```
news = NewsArticle(source=n['Source'],
    url=n['Url'],
    time_ago=n['TimeAgo'],
    date=n['Updated'],
    title=n['Title'],
    content=n['Content'],
    cat=n['Categories'],
    player_id=n['PlayerID'],
    team_id=n['Team'],
    og_source=n['OriginalSource'],
    og_url=n['OriginalSourceUrl'])
```

Comment: The <code>n['PlayerID']</code> in the <code>init_news()</code> function pulls 20001447 which is in the DB. However that number is in the DB as an Integer, and the function is pulling the data as a string and is expecting <code>"20001447"</code> to be in the DB as a string instead of an integer. Even though it is an integer in the JSON.

Comment: @MatthewJarrett did you try out `player_id` while creating `NewsArticle` ? Did that solve your problem ?

Comment: It didn't unfortunately.

I changed the name from `player` to `playerid` to match the name of the primary key in the `Player` model.

It gave me the same error. I also double checked if that PlayerID is in the DB and it is.

Comment: Not `playerid`, can you try with `player_id`, just try the code I wrote above, and in case the player or the team doesn't exist in your DB, the error log should change too, it will be something like this : `relation "......." does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1).............`

Comment: Sorry I forgot the underscore. Lol

After changing `playerid` to `player_id` I got the same error. I did the same for `team` and `team_id`.